# Problems with CS50 - PSet7 Houses Submission

Tags: python, sqlite, cs50

I have written the code for houses both import.py and roster.py and when I test them myself they both work and output exactly the output that the specification expects. Where I have trouble is when I submit it, even though my code works on my end it keeps telling me on check50 (when I submit it) that import.py produces no output at all. I have attached the results from check 50 to show what it says.

Thanks

[check50 results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHogz.png)

**IMPORT.PY**

```
import csv
import sys
from cs50 import SQL

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Usage: python import.py characters.csv")
    sys.exit(1)

db = SQL("sqlite:///students.db")

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as characters:

    reader = csv.DictReader(characters, delimiter=",")

    for row in reader:

        name = row["name"]
        name_list = name.split()

        if len(name_list) == 2:
            first_name = name_list[0]
            last_name = name_list[1]
            db.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, middle, last, house, birth) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                       first_name, None, last_name, row["house"], row["birth"])
        elif len(name_list) == 3:
            first_name = name_list[0]
            middle_name = name_list[1]
            last_name = name_list[2]
            db.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, middle, last, house, birth) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                       first_name, middle_name, last_name, row["house"], row["birth"])
```

**ROSTER.PY**

```
import csv
import sys
from cs50 import SQL

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    if sys.argv[1] != "Gryffindor" or sys.argv[1] != "Slytherin" or sys.argv[1] != "Hufflepuff" or sys.argv[1] != "Ravenclaw":
        print("Usage: python roster.py house")

db = SQL("sqlite:///students.db")

house_list = db.execute("SELECT first, middle, last, birth FROM students WHERE house = (?) ORDER BY last, first", sys.argv[1])

for row in house_list:
    if row["middle"] == None:
        print(row["first"] + " " + row["last"] + ", born " + str(row["birth"]))
    else:
        print(row["first"] + " " + row["middle"] + " " + row["last"] + ", born " + str(row["birth"]))
```

Comment: That is a bit strange. Did you try restarting cs50 IDE? Did you double check that your code works?

Comment: That error occurs when the database in the import.py does not match the database from the distro code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for missing the problem the first go round. When `check50`runs there is already a `students` table in students.db, so the CREATE statement fails. Maybe it's too pedantic, but the spec has no instruction to create the table. As with all psets in this course, one should do and only do what the spec says.